# Interpolating texture coordinates through a perspective transformation

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

My questions are based on the reading of the 13.7 chapter of [Advanced Graphics Progamming using OpenGL](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~manuel/Download/OpenGL_Book/Advanced%20Graphics%20Programming%20Using%20OpenGL%202005.pdf).

The final goal of those questions is to manually compute the needed mipmap level for each pixel.

**FIRST QUESTION:**

**How to correctly compute texture coordinates in window space ?**

I'm not sure to really understand the way the book explains that. It seems that if I want to correctly interpolate my texture coordinate I have to follow the following steps:

In my Vertex Shader:

1. Apply the MVP matrix to my Vertex coordinate (stored in gl_Position)
2. Take my texture coordinates and divide them by the w component of the vertex coordinate, then pass it to the fragment shader (so they'll be interpolated)
3. Compute the 1/w value and pass it to the fragment shader (so they'll be interpolated)

The code would be:

```
vec4 clipCoord = MVP * vertexPosition;
gl_Position = clipCoord;

/*
  assuming vertexTextureCoord is pass as input to the VS.
  So the texture coordinate are in "Texture space".
  outTextureCoord and outInvHomogeneousComponent are pass to the FS
*/
outTextureCoord = vertexTextureCoord / clipCoord.w;
outInvHomogeneousComponent = 1/clipCoord.w;
```

In my Fragment Shader:

1. Multiply the interpolated textureCoordinate by the interpolated 1/w

The code would be:

```
vec2 windowSpaceTextureCoordinate = 
inTextureCoord * inInvHomogeneousComponent;
```

**Are all those things right, or did I miss something ? If Yes, Why ?**

While reading this articles, I assumed some notions such as the method to hyperbolically interpolate the texture coordinate by dividing them the first time by w in VS, and by the interpolated 1/w in the FS. I know it cames from Blinn's articles but I can't figure out in an easy way how it works.

**SECOND QUESTION**

Assuming the first result is correct, Is the method used in this book correct to compute the lod ?
If you read the article, I mean converting the previous result into texel coordinates and use the result to perform partial derivative formulas.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you're trying to achieve here. The GPU alrteady does take care of the perspective correct interpolation, doing the division by w in the vertex shader manually  is almost never a good idea.  Also, you don't need to output `1/clip.w`, since the GL will provide you the per-framgent interpolated `1/w` already in `gl_FragCoord.w`. You seem to not really know what the GPU already does for you, and what not, and it is unclear to me if there is any reason for you to not use that functionality.

Comment: Hi derhass, thank you for your answer. All the things I explained in this post are extracted from the article of the book (did you read it ?). I know what the GPU does for me, If I didn't I could not even try to do advance opengl features. In the end I want to compute the required lod for each fragment, but before I need some relevant information such as texture coordinates in window space to perform partial derivatives. My questions are clear for me, all is explained in the book so if you don't understand what I'm trying to solve, you can try to read the article I put as links.

Comment: On first view, I see nothing obviously wrong. But you are trying to do something that the graphiccard already handles for you. If you want to do manual mipmapping, why not use [`dFdx` and `dFdy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml)? These two methods will exactly contain the partial derivatives of the texture coordinates you are trying to compute without introducing additional overhead.

Comment: @BDL Yes, using the partial derivatives methods are one of the last step to do manual mipmapping. The question is: what kind of texture coordinates the dFdx and dFdy methods take ? Do I only have to pass them interpolated texture coordinates that are in 'texture space" ?

Comment: Since you need to find the correct mipmap level, ypou need to find out how many texels the current pixel's footprint covers, so yes, you need this in texels, and the log2 of that is basically the mipmap level to use. But I have still no idea why you would do that division manually in the VS. Also, there are some errors in your code. You would calculate `texcoord/w` in the VS, and would have to multiply by the per-fragment `w` again. However, you do multiply it by the per-fragment `1/w`. And since the GL will do the correction already, your results will be completely bogus anyway.

Comment: @derhass Sure, this is what I want to do. The code that I wrote is just what the book explains, it's note my code, I just don't understand why people who want to compute mipmapping explained the process this way. Anyway, to compute mipmapping do you state that, from the VS to the FS your texture coordinates have not been transformed except during the interpolation performed by the GPU ? And that these coordinates are juste used to get the Texel coordinates of the fragment (just multiplying them by the texture size ), and finally perform partial derivatives + log2 operations ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I just don't understand why people who want to compute mipmapping explained the process this way.". How else should they describe this computation, if not by using the formula? If there were no perspective distortion, the interpolation would be linear, and the resulting derivatives - and the mipmap level - would be constant across the primitive. For the second part of your question: yes, I would state that - and more importantly, the GL spec does state exactly that - just with the derivatives approximated by discrete differences.

Comment: @derhass By "this way" I mean that they explain the process of computing mipmap level by the interpolation of u/w, v/w, and 1/w, it seems to be useless because you only need to pass u and v and to let the GPU doing its work, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes and no. YOu can use mipmapping and completely ignore the details. But just because the GPU does this for you does not invalidate the explantaion of _how_ the GPU does this. And this is also crucial for situations in which the automatic mipmapping does not work.